# How would you say "gentle reminder" in Ukrainian?

Tags: переклад, from-english, етикет, фразеологізми

I would like to use this phrase in my formal correspondence. Translation with dictionary does not help, it results with something like "M'яке нагадування", which doesn't seem plausible.

Do you have any suggestions or correction or maybe know alternative phrases?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Formal correspondence in Ukrainian is generally a bit more strict than in English. If it is necessary to send a reminder, it is sufficient to say

Нагадуємо вам, що...

Хочемо нагадати про...

and add "Дуже дякуємо" or similar at the end.

"М'яко нагадуємо" is acceptable and is becoming more common due to globalization, but still has a distinct feeling of using an English phrase in Ukrainian.

Answer (score 15):

You should use the 'делікатне нагадування'.

[This article](http://dilomova.org.ua/?p=583) at DiloMova provides with several different ways to translate *"gentle reminder"*, depending on your attitude to the nature of the matter being reminded of.

Comment: Sure. Sorry. I was interrupted and aave simultaneously sent the answer. Refer to [http://dilomova.org.ua/?p=583](this page). The word "Делікатний" should seem more official than others

Answer (score 0):

The word "gentle" can be translated in a number of ways into Ukrainian, there is no Ukrainian word that corresponds to "gentle" one-to-one. "M’яке нагадування" sounds pretty well ("soft reminder"), but if you do not like it, maybe "лагідне нагадування" will suit you better. "Лагідний" is much close to "gentle" in its meaning than "м’який".

Answer (score -1):

I guess the best translation is **натяк**. According to [Glosbe](https://uk.glosbe.com/uk/en/%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F) disctionary it's **тактовне нагадування**.

Comment: The question was asked specifically about the usage of this phrase in formal correspondence. Using "натяк" in this context would be incorrect.